# Monadic Predicate and Polyadic Predicate?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Consider the following sentences; how would each be symbolized?:

"Kate loves John" vs. "Kate loves cheese"

^(here, I'm trying to understand the difference between a relation between two individuals vs. a relation between an individual and a class of things)

"Jane has tattoos" vs. "Jane is tatted"

^(here, I'm trying to understand whether terms like 'has' can be expressed both as relations and as simple predicates)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need a binary *preidcate* **Loves(x,y)**.

With individuals, you need individual *constants* : **Kate** and **John**.

Thus, the first sentence will be :

> **Loves(Kate, John)**.

For the second one, we can use a unary *predicate* : **Cheese(x)** to mean that "**x** is a **Cheese**".

Thus, the second sentence will be :

> **∀x (Cheese (x) → Loves (Kate,x))**.

---

Regarding the second example, I'll suggest :

> **Tat(Jane)**.

We do not need an "has" predicate